# Eclipse - Extract Local Variable fails with semi colon

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

In Eclipse I'm using the `Extract Local Variable`

But in failed to extract when variable is in return statement line when with semi colon (`;`) is marked, e.g.

```
return ps.executeUpdate() > 0;
```

I expect to extract to simple boolean variable

```
boolean result = ps.executeUpdate() > 0;
return result;
```

[image]

Why this error persist? is it an eclipse bug or I'm expecting invalid refactoring option?

**EDIT**

As @howlger suggested opened an [enhancement](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548553)

Comment: What if the semicolon isn't selected? The semicolon is part of the statement, not of the expression.

Comment: @tkausl it works, the issue is the semi colon

Comment: @user7294900 The semicolon is not part of the expression (regarding the Java language specification). You could report a feature request to Eclipse that a trailing semicolon should be ignored in this case, ideally with a patch (Eclipse is Open Source and written in Java and you are a Java developer).

Comment: It's not a bug, it's how it's supposed to work. You are supposed to select an expression, not an expression and some extra, unrelated characters.

Comment: @howlger I need to download source from https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.12-201906051800/#JDTSDK ?

Comment: @user7294900 See https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_UI/How_to_Contribute